# http://[DOMAIN].de.de:443/ always shows the same site

Tags: dns, tld

I just played around with some URLs and found out that requesting

http://[DOMAIN].de.de:443/

Always shows this message:

> Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand. Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled
>   server port. Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
>   Hint: default-62_116_182_44 Apache Server at
>   default-62_116_182_44 Port 443

Opening the IP "62.116.182.44" shows "Parallels Plesk".

Try some domains:

> test.de.de:443/
>
> stuff.de.de:443/
>
> dasjkdsakjdsajkjkdsa.de.de:443/

My question: Who is responsible for this? Denic?

Answer (score 0):

You request a HTTP resource on port 443, where usually HTTPS servers reside. The server catches the invalid usage (because your request does not look like the start of a SSL handshake, but instead like a HTTP request) and replies to it in a way the browser can understand, e.g. by responding with an error message inside a HTTP response.

This has nothing to do with DENIC, its the setup of the web server by the owner of host.